# Why do build constraints exclude all Go files in '/Users/rpurusho/go/src/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1'?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write a program in Go and I see the above error when I try to import a library from google.golang.org/api/compute/v1

Given below is the code snippet..

```
package main

import (

    "log"
    "fmt"
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"

    _ "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"

)
```

Does anyone know what this issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons why that can occur for you:

1. simply your library is empty or your download process has been interrupted
2. Maybe your pkg is separated
3. Can be the compiler problem which u can find out [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24068)

Comment: "your pkg is separated": What does "separated" mean?